# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Добрый день!
Начал писать тесты junit на веб-приложение, но выскакивает ошибка, понимаю, что не может найти класс. Но вопрос в том, как от нее избавиться?

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.<clinit>(NamingContext.java:60)
at org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.getInitialContext(javaURLContextFactory.java:112)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ua.nure.martseniuk.SummaryTask4.db.dao.MySqlDaoFactoryTest.init(MySqlDaoFactoryTest.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 22 more
```

Comment: пробовал добавить в зависимости этот класс? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/juli/6.0.45

Comment: да, получилось) но не могу понять при чем здесь эта библиотека?

Comment: видимо сторонняя либа которая у тебя в проекте использует этот логгер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в зависимости добавить следующую библиотеку:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>juli</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.45</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: да, я это понял. а для чего она нужна, почему без нее тесты не работают?

Comment: хз, сложно сказать, можешь запустить mvn dependency:tree чтобы посмотреть зависимости по библиотекам. Из данной информации узнаешь какая либа имеет в зависимотях juli